# Spark SQL over Streaming - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code to launch an SQL query on streaming. My problem is that after one of the results show an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Why does this happen?

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

object StreamingSQL {

   case class Persons(name: String, age: Int)

   def main(args: Array[String]) {

       val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("HdfsWordCount")
       val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
       // Create the context
       val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

      val lines = ssc.textFileStream("/home/cloudera/Smartcare/stream/")
      lines.foreachRDD(rdd=>rdd.foreach(println))

      val sqc = new SQLContext(sc);
      //import sqc.createSchemaRDD
       import sqc.implicits._

     // Create the FileInputDStream on the directory and use the
     // stream to count words in new files created

      lines.foreachRDD{rdd=>
           val persons = rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Persons(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
           persons.registerTempTable("data")
           val teenagers = sqc.sql("SELECT name FROM data WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
           teenagers.foreach(println)
     }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
   }
}
```

This is the output I get. After a correct result , I skip the error:

```
16/03/23 16:58:56 INFO GenerateUnsafeProjection: Code generated in 131.828141 ms
[Edgar]
16/03/23 16:58:56 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

My txt is:

```
Ana,31
Edgar,16
Luis,22
Noelia,26
Isabel50
Pablo,34
Laura,18
Paco,17
```

Comment: I would start by checking if the actually data in the RDD has two fields.

Comment: I checked that the RDD has two fields..

Comment: I can't test it now but it's good that you've provided at least an input data sample. Can you try to check if it give you the same error if you read it as a whole RDD and that perform the transformation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `Isabel50` has no comma. Your `split(",")` is only returning one value for that row, so `p(1)` fails for that row.